# creating a filter using multiple criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm attempting to build a filter with three criteria and am having no luck.

so, [Lane] and [callnbr] values are integers

```
 Me.Filter = "[Lane] = 14" & " And [CallNbr] = 8" & " OR [CallNbr] = 3"
 Me.FilterOn = True
```

this is probably really simple but it's driving me up a wall.  The goal is to use multiple [callnbr]'s in the statement.

i'm a self-taught novice and the manual I have is not much help.  Thanks for any help in advance.

The Old Guy

Answer (score 3):

`AND` has higher precedence than `OR`.

So your filter is actually

```
([Lane] = 14 AND [CallNbr] = 8) OR [CallNbr] = 3
```

and you get all records with `[CallNbr] = 3`, no matter what lane.

Use parentheses, so your filter results in:

```
[Lane] = 14 AND ([CallNbr] = 8 OR [CallNbr] = 3)
```

or you could do

```
[Lane] = 14 AND [CallNbr] IN (8, 3)
```

Comment: thanks!  i'm going to try this in the morning.  will let you know if it worked.

Comment: Andre, your suggestion worked!  Thanks.  I built the orginal pgm using access 97 then retired in 2003.  for some reason the commander needs it modified for the bowling center and installed.  What a change.  Thanks again.